# NSNotification touch overlay

Tags: objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, nsnotificationcenter

4 files for 2 view controllers, firstviewcontroller and MyOverlayView. MyOverlayView just receives touches and sends notification which should be received by firstviewcontroller. Im getting touch event on the overlayview but not receiving the notification at firstviewcontroller. Any ideas?

FVC-Header

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import "MyOverlayView.h"

extern NSString *const OverlayViewTouchNotification;

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *mvc;
    MyOverlayView *overlayView;
    NSArray *keyArray;
    NSMutableDictionary *urlDic;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) MPMoviePlayerViewController *mvc;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MyOverlayView *overlayView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *keyArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *urlDic;

-(void)playMovieAtURL:(NSDictionary *)dic:(NSArray *)array:(int) rand;
-(void)overlayViewTouches:(NSNotification *)notification;
-(void)loadArray;
-(void)reset;
@end
```

FVC-Implementation

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "SMWebRequest.h"

NSString * const OverlayViewTouchNotification = @"overlayViewTouch";

@implementation FirstViewController
@synthesize mvc;
@synthesize overlayView;
@synthesize keyArray, urlDic;

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self loadArray];
    if (!overlayView) {
        overlayView = [[MyOverlayView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
    }
    NSArray *windows = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];
    if ([windows count] >= 1)
    {
        // Locate the movie player window
        UIWindow *moviePlayerWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
        // Add our overlay view to the movie player's subviews so it is 
        // displayed above it.
        [moviePlayerWindow addSubview:self.overlayView];
    }

    //[self.parentViewController.view addSubview:overlayView];
}

-(void)loadArray{
    if (!urlDic) {
        NSMutableDictionary *tempDic = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        [tempDic setObject:@"mp4" forKey:@"euromount_high_res"];

        urlDic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:tempDic];
    }

    if (!keyArray) {
        NSArray *tempArray = [urlDic allKeys];
        keyArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:tempArray];
    }
    //Random choice
    int point = rand() % ([keyArray count]);
    //Call play movie
    [self playMovieAtURL :urlDic :keyArray :point];
}

-(void)playMovieAtURL:(NSDictionary *)dic:(NSArray *)array:(int)rand
{   
    NSString *key = [array objectAtIndex:rand];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:key ofType:[dic valueForKey:key]];


    if (mvc == nil) { mvc = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]]; }

    mvc.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
    mvc.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = TRUE;
    mvc.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;

    // Register for the playback finished notification.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(myMovieFinishedCallback:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:nil];

    [self presentModalViewController:mvc animated:YES];

    // Movie playback is asynchronous, so this method returns immediately. 
    [mvc.moviePlayer play];
} 

// When the movie is done,release the controller. 
-(void)myMovieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*)aNotification 
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                                  object:nil]; 
    //for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
    //    [view removeFromSuperview];
    //}
    mvc = nil;
    [self loadArray];
}

// Touches in the overlay view (not in the overlay button)
// post the "overlayViewTouch" notification and will send
// the overlayViewTouches: message
- (void)overlayViewTouches:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"screen touched");
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    mvc = nil;
    keyArray = nil;
    urlDic = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

-(void)reset{
    for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
    mvc = nil;
    keyArray = nil;
    urlDic = nil;
    [self loadArray];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

MyOverlayView-Header

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface MyOverlayView : UIView {
}

- (void)awakeFromNib;
- (void)dealloc;
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

@end
```

MyOverlayView-Implementation

```
#import "MyOverlayView.h"
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@implementation MyOverlayView

// MPMoviePlayerController will play movies full-screen in 
// landscape mode, so we must rotate MyOverlayView 90 degrees and 
// translate it to the center of the screen so when it draws
// on top of the playing movie it will display in landscape 
// mode to match the movie player orientation.
//
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    CGAffineTransform transform = self.transform;

    // Rotate the view 90 degrees. 
    transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, (M_PI / 2.0));

    UIScreen *screen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
    // Translate the view to the center of the screen
    transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 
        ((screen.bounds.size.height) - (self.bounds.size.height))/2, 
        0);
    self.transform = transform;

    CGRect newFrame = self.frame;
    newFrame.origin.x = 190;
    self.frame = newFrame;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

// Handle any touches to the overlay view
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    if (touch.phase == UITouchPhaseBegan)
    {
        NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        [nc postNotificationName:OverlayViewTouchNotification object:nil];
    }    
}


@end
```

*****EDIT ANSWER****************
I wasnt adding an observer for the notification. Got it all sorted out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't adding an observer for the notification. Got it all Sorted out